# Referencing a non-namespaced controller from within a namespace block in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a definition in `routes.rb` that is something like this:

```
namespace :admin do
    resources :users do
        resources :email_addresses, controller: 'email_addresses'
    end
end
```

The two controllers that exist are `Admin::UsersController` and `EmailAddressesController`. The problem I'm seeing is that once I deploy the app to production, trying to access any of the links for the email addresses resource results in a 404 and an uninitialized constant error for `Admin::EmailAddressesController`. For whatever reason, this isn't happening in my development environment.

Here's the output from my production environment log:

```
Started GET "/admin/users/3/email_addresses/new" for 192.168.206.6 at 2013-08-21 10:00:43 -0700
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Admin::EmailAddressesController):
```

Here it is in my development environment working just fine:

```
Started GET "/admin/users/1/email_addresses/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-21 10:03:04 -0700
Processing by EmailAddressesController#new as JS
```

Strange, right?

Here is an example of the link that I'm using that results in an error (once clicked):

```
link_to "Add Email Address", new_admin_user_email_address_path(user)
```

**UPDATE:** It seems as though the issue may be related to the issue mentioned in this bug report: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5798 . Question is, how do I explicitly reference the non-namespaced controller in `controller:` ?

Comment: Can you include samples of the link formats you tried, and what you would expect to work?